# Start Docker with python subprocess for a command line utility

Tags: python, subprocess

I confused as to why the following code returns an error:

```
import subprocess

a = subprocess.Popen(["docker-compose down weather-data"])
a.wait()
```

I get as an error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'docker-compose down weather-data'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your command needs to be in an array with each part of the command as one element in the array. For example:

```
import subprocess
a = subprocess.Popen(["docker-compose", "down", "weather-data"])
a.wait()
```

If it's all in one string, Python is trying to find a single executable named "docker-compose down weather-data".

Comment: - thank you! Let me know if you can help with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67765890/open-up-docker-query-postgress-db-save-results-as-csv